# ActiveRecord attribute dynamically changing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a scenario where I have a activerecord model called client.  These clients have an attribute called order.  Right now, let's assume there are 10 clients ordered 1-10.  If I create a new client and want to give it the order of 3, I have to manually change all the other clients.

In this scenario, is there a way that if I did create a new client and assign it with a order of 3 that every clients who's order was >= 3 would add one to it's original order?

From the community, I see that ranked-order is something to look into.  I am also displaying the order of the clients in the admin (activeadmin column).  Let's say we have those 10 clients and I decide take number 5 and move it to number 3.  I realize ranked order would change the order accordingly, but will it also change the order column in the admin where all clients after the new number 2 will be bumped down one spot?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [ranked-model](https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model), as it does this quite cleverly.

Imagine you have three clients. Instead of giving it a sequential position

```
Client#1: position 1
Client#2: position 2
Client#3: position 3
```

it leaves huge gaps in between:

```
Client#1: position -10000
Client#2: position 10000
Client#3: position 20000
```

This way, if one position changes, in most cases it only has to update the one record that has changed:

```
    Client#3: position 5000 -> second place
```

Only when it runs out of space between two records does it have to modify more than one in order to make more space.

Comment: I am using activeadmin and allowing the admin to manually change the position of a client.  So if the admin goes in there and changes a client from order 5 to order 2, using ranked-model, how would this dynamically change all the other clients?  While ranked-model might change this behind the scenes, will it update activeadmin?

Comment: ranked-model would check how far the current client #1 and #2 are apart, then change the position of client #5 to be right in between them.

Comment: But in the admin where order is listed 1,2,3,4, etc for an user to see, will those numbers be updated as well?  For example will the spot that used to be 4 now change to 5?

Comment: I do not know activeadmin or whether it would work with any kind of ranking. If that is what you want to achieve, I would suggest updating your question to include that.